# Next.js 13 and next-auth issues with useSession and SessionProvider

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

I'm trying to make a login page. on my page.tsx file I get either of two errors depending on if I include "use client"; at the top of my code.  If I don't have "use client"; I get this error:
`Error: React Context is unavailable in Server Components`
if I do use "use client"; I get this error:
`Error: [next-auth]:` useSession `must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider />`

this is my layout.tsx file:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import React from 'react';

import "./globals.css";
import Link from "next/link";

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
  session: any;
};

export default function Layout({ children, session }: Props) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head />
      <body>
        <div className="mx-auto">
          <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap">
            <aside className="w-full sm:w-1/3 md:w-1/5 xl:w-1/6 border-r-2 border-[#F845C6]">
              <div className="sticky top-0 p-4 w-full">
                <ul className="flex flex-col overflow-hidden">
                  <li className="m-5 text-center">
                    <Link href="login">LOGO</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="m-5 text-center">
                    <Link href="/">Dashboard</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="m-5 text-center">
                    <Link href="tasks">Tasks</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li className="m-5 text-center">
                    <Link href="reporting">Reporting</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </aside>

            <div className="w-full sm:w-2/3 md:w-4/5 xl:w-5/6">{children}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export function getLayout(page: any) {
  const { session } = page.props;

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Layout session={session}>{page}</Layout>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
```

this is the login page.tsx file:

```
"use client";
import React from 'react'
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import { getLayout } from '../components/Layout'

export default function Login() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  console.log(session);

  if (session) {
    return (
      <div style={{ fontFamily: 'sans-serif', margin: '10px 20px' }}>
        <p>Welcome, {session.user.name}</p>
        <img src={session.user.image} alt="" style={{ borderRadius: '15px', width: '80px', margin: '10px' }} />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Please sign in</p>
        <button onClick={() => signIn("google", { callbackUrl: '/account' })}>Sign in with Google</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.getLayout = function getLayout(page: any) {
  return getLayout(page);
};
```

Im trying to move from a older project to one tht uses the app directory. I tried to add the SessionProvider code that was in the original _app.js file to the root layout but Im not having any luck

Answer (score 28):

For anyone else encountering this page, and in case you never resolved the issue, The SessionProvider simply needs to be wrapped in a client component which is used in the server-rendered layout, instead of being applied in the layout directly.

make a provider file:

```js
"use client";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export const NextAuthProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};
```

and then use it in your root layout like so:

```js
type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};
    
export default function RootLayout({ children }: Props) {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <NextAuthProvider>
      ...
      {children}
      ...
    </NextAuthProvider>
    ...
  );
}
```

This will give you access to the session context in all client-side components across the site, which is typically what you would want.

Comment: You can just do ```"use client"
export { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";```

Comment: Does it mean if I develop admin app it will never be rendered on server?

Comment: yes, I think that's the issue with useSession. It seems it's built with the intent of being used on the browser

Answer (score 8):

You can re-export your SessionProvider from a client component in 2 lines:

```
"use client";

export { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
```

This works for other 3rd party components that you want to turn into client components as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
'use client'

export { SessionProvider as AuthProvider } from 'next-auth/react'
```

To make sure you're using the client-side provider, make a file like ^ and then consume it. You don't need to rewrite the component as a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

i simply made the Auth Provider wrapper and the useSession hook (as  client component). Most of the solutions suggest here didn't work out for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).