# _app is ignored on Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I added the _app.tsx file to my project to wrap my projects in next-auth SessionProvider, but my project ignore my _app.tsx, I added a div with bg set to orange on the _app.tsx and it doesn’t affect my project

https://github.com/LifeAsDev/next-js-mongodb-authentication

The _app.tsx work and stop the error on /dashboard page of Error: [next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a SessionProvider

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the app directory the SessionProvider has to be in a client component.

Either just export SessionProvider from a client component or create a wrapper component (depending on if you want/need the wrapping component or not).

Basically this

[Next.js 13 and next-auth issues with useSession and SessionProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75902311/next-js-13-and-next-auth-issues-with-usesession-and-sessionprovider)

Some random tutorial.
https://nextjsdev.com/user-authentication-in-nextjs-13-app-using-nextauth/

Comment: Please do not link to the solution, instead copy the relevant portions of the links to your answer in case the link changes.

Comment: @AaronMeese I Copy the relevant information, just add the link because the source is also useful.